# Weird 0 byte files in root

Tags: centos, files

In the root of several of our old CentOS machines (CentOS release 5.8 (Final)) In the root of the ext3 file system I see the following:

[image: wtf.]

I've removed some of these, but they seem to continue coming back.

Here are the timestamps

```
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2011-12-15 01:20 .?????????????????????????????????????????????????Z]Y?+
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2011-12-16 01:14 .???????????????????????????????????????????????????ֽ*
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2011-12-20 01:20 .?????????????????????????????????????????????????????*
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2011-12-22 01:23 .??????????????????????????????????????????????????\X?*
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2011-12-26 01:20 .????????????????????????????????????????????????????]+
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2012-01-01 01:16 .?????????????????????????????????????????????????*???+
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2012-01-04 01:15 .?????????????????????????????????????????????????????*
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2012-01-11 01:14 .???????????????????????????????????????????????????;?+
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2012-01-12 01:17 .?????????????????????????????????????????????????ZF.?*
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2012-02-29 01:16 .?????????????????????????????????5?;J+
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2012-02-29 01:17 .???????????????????????????????????e?*
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2012-03-01 01:16 .??????????????????????????????????B)Q+
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2012-03-06 01:08 .??????????????????????????????????'??+
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2012-03-07 01:09 .?????????????????????????????????%?F?+
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2012-03-22 01:07 .?????????????????????????????????%??+
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2012-04-06 01:12 .?????????????????????????????????????*
-rw-rw----   1 root   root       0 2012-05-06 01:16 ??X?7+.?????????????????u{?7+
```

Comment: do these machines with the odd filenames have a direct connection to the internet?

Comment: @MikePennington Yes

Comment: Can you tell me what `PermitRootLogin` is set to in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency ? :)

Comment: I don't think we're being attacked, SSH port is locked outside of our network. So I'm not worried about PermitRootLogin

Comment: I think Janne is onto something. Try `ls -lart --time-style=long-iso` to get them sorted by time with the full timestamp (so it shows time for everything) is it always around 01:10?  The variation in time could be if it's something like a backup script that is creating the file whenever it ends.

Comment: @DerfK I've added the output, it is certainly around the same time, only seemingly scattered on the dates.

Answer (score 3):

Those seem to appear approximately the same time at near 01:10. Could there be a buggy cron job creating those files?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. Are you running rsyslog / syslog-ng ... or any other logging daemon  ? I bet that it's a rule running wild. If you are using rsyslog check working directory and your rules.

Also you can try with lsof and if you are lucky the descriptor will be still alive and you will find the corresponding app.

Comment: Care to detail how I can lsof a file name like that?

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Go with `find / -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec lsof {} +`

Comment: Yields no results